# Selenium(chrome) crashes on navigate

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I am trying to open url with Selenium and Google chrome, however i always end up with chromedriver.has stopped working.

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"Path\To\The\Driver");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

i tried to sleep between initializing and going to url, however it does nothing.

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using? I can't repro with chrome-driver 2.25 but I can with 2.9.

Comment: Yes, i am using 2.9, i will try with 2.2.5

Comment: With 2.2.5 works just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, chromedriver version 2.25 will work. The problem with version 2.25 is that it crashes when running. You can see here the update history.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/download .

I would suggest you use a later version of the driver. 
Here is the link to the drivers that was given to me by visual studio. http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com

Choose a chrome driver version 2.37 for windows selenium version 3.11.1.

Answer (score 0):

Any news on this topic? I have the same issue. The execution stops at driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(desiredUri); where the login window is shown. It waits for me to enter the username and password and manually it can be done but the execution has stopped there and it does not go to my next line var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert(); from where I want to add the username and password.